# $p$-adic closures of infinite sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $S\subsetneq\mathbb{Z}$ be an infinite set.  Does there always exist a prime $p$ such that the closure of $S$ in the $p$-adic integers, $\mathbb{Z}_p$, contains a rational integer $n\notin S$?

Or, in elementary language, does there always exist a prime $p$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus S$ such that for all $k$ there is an $s\in S$ such that $p^k\mid n-s$.

Comment: Okay, I moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about $S = \{ 0 \} \cup \{ n! : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$?